# Debugging Issues using iOS Web Inspector

Tags: iphone, asp.net-mvc, debugging, razor, ios11.3

I have a web application project which is built using asp.net mvc. It is built with custom views for mobile devices and combines a combination of knockout and razor bindings. The app started crashing when iOS upgraded to version 11.3.1 on one specific page. The error is specific to that iOS version  11.3.1 on mobile. On any Android device or desktop , including Safari, it works. On any older version of iOS it works also. In order to debug and recreate the error I want to view the console logs in developer tools . To do that I connected the mobile  device to desktop Mac and used the Mac web inspector tools.

But here is the catch. As soon as I connected to desktop Web Inspector and ran the page again, the page worked on my mobile device. As soon as I disconnected , it stopped working again. It is as though the connection of the mobile device  to the desktop's Web Inspector altered the running of the page on my mobile device.

Is there any way to prevent the Web Inspector in Safari interfering with the  actual operation of a page on a mobile device?

Alternatively , is there any alternative method anyone would have to debug the latest iOS version?  (I researched existing emulators such as browserstack , however they do not support the latest iOS version)